# Conflict in Using @RepositoryRestController and @RepositoryRestResource For a Single Resource in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a Payment entity in my spring boot application. Considering all possible CRUD operations, I'm using spring data rest for `read` and want to implement a custom `create` operation. Also `delete` and `update` are not allowed for this entity.

So this is my desired URLs and resoponsible component for each one:

`GET /payments` : PaymentRepository

`GET /payments/{id}` : PaymentRepository

`POST /payments` : PaymentController

This is my repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PaymentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Payment, Long> {

    // disable create and update
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    Payment save(Payment entity);

    // disable delete
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void delete(Payment entity);
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/payments")
public class PaymentController {

    @PostMapping("")
    @ResponseBody
    public Payment create() {
        // some code...
    }

}
```

If I map `create` operation to a url like `POST /payments/create`, everything works fine, but If I use the above code and map `create` to `POST /payments`, the `GET /payments` url does not work any more and I get `405 Method Not Allowed` error. (`GET /payments/{id}` is still working)

It seems in this case presence of `@PostMapping("")` annotation, cause the `PaymentController` to responsd the `GET /payments` request and it fails.

I hope my explanations were clear. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Spring Data REST reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers) states that:

> Sometimes you may want to write a custom handler for a specific resource. To take advantage of Spring Data REST’s settings, message converters, exception handling, and more, use the `@RepositoryRestController` annotation instead of a standard Spring MVC @Controller or @RestController.

It is not explicitly mentionned, but annotating your controller with `@RepositoryRestController` also allows you to define a custom behavior for one endpoint while keeping all the other endpoints that Spring automatically generates... On one condition: the `@RequestMapping` annotation can only be used at the [method level](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-535) (this is actually what is done in the example of the reference documentation).

Your example becomes:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class PaymentController {

    @PostMapping("/payments")
    @ResponseBody
    public Payment create() {
        // some code...
    }

}
```

With this, you get your custom endpoint mapped to `POST /payments` requests, plus all endpoints automatically generated by Spring, minus the ones annotated with `@RestResource(exported = false)`.

Comment: No I get `405 Method Not Allowed` for `POST /payments` request.

Comment: Weird, I use that all the time. What are the URL mappings listed in your startup log?

Answer (score 2):

```
@BasePathAwareController
@RepositoryRestController
public class PaymentController {

    @PostMapping("/payments")
    @ResponseBody
    public Payment create() {
        // some code...
    }

}
```

You should modify your controller in the above way. @BasePathAwareController enables the custom REST URI's to get registered under your base URI.
With the above modification : both API's can work fine.